# Why are my column sorts slow in Django Admin, only 1 problem table

Tags: mysql, django, optimization, admin

I have a table (MySQL) with 10K+ records.  Not a huge table.  When working with the table in Django's Admin, the default sort order, the page loads blazing fast.  Hardly noticeable.

But if I attempt to sort by any column, say by ID column or even a date column, it can take over a minute to return results.  **Other tables work fine**

Any clues?

If more info is needed, add a comment to my question so I know what to add.

Thanks.

```
class Link(models.Model):
    from_page        = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='linked_to_set')
    to_page          = models.ForeignKey(Page, related_name='linked_from_set')
    data_source      = models.ForeignKey(Data_Source)
    moz_rank         = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    raw_score        = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    date             = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    anchor_text      = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    hover_text       = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    no_follow        = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    same_subdomain   = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    meta_refresh     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    same_ip_address  = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    same_c_block     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    redirect_301     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    redirect_302     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    no_script        = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    off_screen       = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    meta_no_follow   = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    same_root_domain = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    feed_autodiscovery = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    rel_canonical      = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    via_301            = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.to_page.url
```

Answer (score 1):

You need indexes on your data.

Add `db_index=True` to the fields that you will frequently want to sort by.

Ie. change:

```
models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

to:

```
models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

Don't add more than indexes than you really need, because they will slow inserts to the table and updates on the affected columns.

There is a lot more to indexing databases than this, but this might be a quick fix for your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks.  Is this something that will require running 'manage.py syncdb', manual edits to MySQL, or a combination?

Comment: syncdb will not apply the changes. You will have to manually add the indexes in MySQL using `CREATE INDEX` statements.

Comment: If you need to manually add the indexes yourself, then why do you also need to modify your Django fields?

Comment: @JonathanHartley Modifying your Django fields will mean that if you delete and recreate the table from scratch it will already have the right indexes. It also means that the change is documented in your code and source control system.